# How do I replace a word in a text file with another word and an action?

Tags: file, text, replace, newline, hidden-characters

hi all
Suppose we have a text file (file1.txt)

file1.txt contains many words and spaces and enter characters (cR+LF). 
I wanna to replace a specific word that follows with an enter character and replace it with only that word. I mean eliminating cr+lf character.

How ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use of regular expressions should make short work of this:

replace `word\r\n` with `word`

How this is exactly done depends on your environment / editor / tools. You mentioned cf + lf, which hints that you're using Windows.

If you use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for example, it has builtin regex support and you can use these facilities to obtain your goal.

**Update**: I have tried this variant it works:

Download [Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) for Windows.

Open your file in Vim.

In it, issue the following command:

```
%s/\v([[:digit:]]+NPN[[:alpha:]]+)\n/\1  /g
```

Explanation:

```
%s - work for all lines
\v - easier regex manipulation regarding backslashes
([[:digit:]]+NPN[[:alpha:]]+) - match some digits, then NPN, then letters and capture this
\n - match end of line
\1   - replace everything with first group and two spaces
g - do this many times for each line (this is basically optional)
```

Comment: Well, There are many different forms of my specific word. for example if my key word is NPN there are words like 02NPNPAGLUBE, 12NPNSEALANT and .... but the problem is at the end of all these words, there is a paragraph mark (enter character) and I wanna to eliminate it and put 2 spaces.  How? How can I point to word ?

Answer (score 0):

i assume you're asking about how to do it programmatically.
LF and CR are characters and as such they have an ascii code assigned (10,13). you'll need to load the text file, copy it to a new buffer word by word and whenever you encounter the word you want to replace - check whether it is followed by 10,13 and just don't copy those characters if so.
then write the new buffer back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert CRLF to LF:

```
sed 's/.$//'               # assumes that all lines end with CR/LF
```

If you want to remove CRLF altogether

```
cat file1.txt | tr '\n' ' '   # join the lines with a space
cat file1.txt | tr -d '\n'    # join the lines without a space
```

You might have to convert the line endings to unix (CRLF to LF) first and then do the translation.